# Правильно ли написание этого слова?

Tags: орфография

"Мы вчера говорили о той мышки, которую ты потерял двадцать дней тому назад".

Меня интересует, правильно ли я просклонял существительное **мышка**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правильно: "Мы вчера говорили о той мышке, которую ты потерял двадцать дней тому назад".

Мышка - существительное 1-ого склонения, в П.п. окончание Е (можно проверить: о мышке - о стене).

Сравнить: о той мыши - окончание И для сущ. 3-его склонения.

Comment: А, точно. Мышка и мышь –– слова, которые относятся к разным склонениям. :) Все, я просто невнимательный был.